# Creating Xpath based policy with WSO2 identity entitlement module

Tags: xml, xpath, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 identity server 4.5.0. I would like to add a policy with a rule that governs how to access a certain location in a resource. The resource in my case is an RDF or XML based file. The file has different elements (e.g.  or  etc.).

I tried to use xPath to achieve my goal but I am unable to do that in the Basic Policy Editor in WSO2 IS. I tried to use the configuration console to add more elements. I saw xpath listed as a datatype but not function. I tried to add one but got an error.

Any clues on how to do that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

XPath evaluation is already mentioned in the XACML core specification. I guess It is supported by most of the XACML implementation. [Balana](http://xacmlinfo.org/category/balana/) is an open source XACML 3.0 library that is supported XPath. you can find XPath samples (policies and requests) in Balana [text cases](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-core/src/test/resources/basic/3/policies/).  However WSO2 identity server is using Balana implementation. Therefore it must support for XPath.  WSO2 Identity Server's policy editors are not supported to create XPath based policies. (basically AttributeSelector element). IMO, Policy editor can not support all.. :) However you can upload policy that you have written in to Identity server. Simple scenario on using XPath can be found [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/10/30/xpath-in-xacml-part-1/). This blog post contains sample policy and request that may help you to get some idea.